# Inserting flash photo gallery into html css template

Tags: javascript, css, flash

I've pretty much taught myself everything about editing html so far, but this one is loosing me quickly. I've downloaded a html css template, edited out the fat i don't need, so on and so forth, now all I need is a photo gallery. However, I'm not sure how to embed the flash template to get it to run. I'm trying to use a sliding gallery, but can't seem to get it.

Comment: Do you have some code examples which highlights where you are going to embed the flash, and what is going to support it - or is currently supporting it?

Comment: <div class="menu_nav">
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="residential projects.html">Residential Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="commercial projects.html">Commercial Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="marketing services.html">Marketing Services</a></li>
          
        <li><a href="photo gallery.html">Photo Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
      </div>
      <div class="logo">

Comment: so that is the section i want it to embed in. What I'm trying to do is make the a href="photo gallery.html"> open a new screen, in the same window preferably, and have a sliding flash gallery appear. I don't currently know how to make a .swf file. I was trying to use a flash template (http://smoothgallery.jondesign.net/) i downloaded, edit the pictures from the source file, and embed it that way.

Answer (score 0):

The below HTML is how I go about embedding the **.swf** into a page.

```
<object width="" height="">
    <!--
        <param> tags are optional
        <param name="" value="" />
    -->
    <embed width="" height="" src="file.swf" />
</object>
```